# WatchKit crash on sendResponse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit

My app is crashing and I can't track down the bug.

Its telling me on the crash:

**`Assertion failure in -[UIWatchKitExtensionRequestAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-98.3/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221`**

```
 **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'**

 **First throw call stack:
(0x1823342d8 0x193b580e4 0x182334198 0x1831e8ed4 0x188812ab4 0x10003cf94 0x10004708c 0x188812a08 0x18745dab4 0x18871f778 0x10003cfd4 0x10003cf94 0x10004ab54 0x10004c248 0x19438922c 0x194388ef0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
```

I tried putting an exception breakpoint in, and still can't track it down.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
    if (userInfo[@"pfquery_request"]) {
        NSLog(@"Starting PFQuery"); // won't print out to console since you're running the watch extension

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *dateTodayShort = [dateToday substringToIndex:[dateToday length] -6];

        // Get JSON file path
        NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Days" ofType:@"json"];
        NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
        NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSArray *days;
        days = JSONDictionary[@"days"];

        // Iterate thru JSON to find Data for Today
        NSObject *todayJson;
        for (NSObject *object in days) {
            NSString *dateObject = [object valueForKey:@"day"];
            if ([dateObject isEqualToString:dateTodayShort]) {
                todayJson = object;
                NSString *textToday = [todayJson valueForKey:@"text"];

                // App Group
                NSString *container = @"group.com.rr.mm";
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];
                [defaults setValue:textToday forKey:@"textSaved"];
            }
        }
        reply(@{@"success": @(YES)});
    }
    reply(@{@"success": @(NO)});
}
```

I request the data in both my WatchKit `InterfaceController.m` and my WatchKit `GlanceController.m` with the same thing:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [WKInterfaceController
         openParentApplication:@{@"pfquery_request": @"dumm_val"}
         reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"User Info: %@", replyInfo);
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

             if ([replyInfo[@"success"] boolValue]) {

                 // Get Saved data
                 NSString *container = @"group.com.rr.mm";
                 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];
                 NSString *text = [defaults valueForKey:@"textSaved"];

                 // Set Saved Data to Global String
                 textGlobal = text;

                 // Set text Label
                 self.textVerseLabelWatch.text = text;
             }
         }];
    });
}
```

Comment: We're not magicians, please provide code where you call `-sendResponse` and any other necessary code.

Comment: @Schemetrical added some code, thanks!!

Comment: Bingo, error found :D

Comment: Can we see the WatchKit extension code where you're actually calling this and surrounding code? It seems to me now that `-application: handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:` is being called twice.

Comment: @Schemetrical Just added the extension code.  Let me know if you see anything or have any advice on how to better set that up, because you seem like you have a really good handle on all of this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `userInfo[@"pfquery_request"]` exists, the `if` statement will pass and the code will run inside the if statement, including `reply(@{@"success": @(YES)});`. Immediately after, **regardless of if the `if` statement passes or not**, it will run `reply(@{@"success": @(NO)});`. This is why its called twice.

Use the following instead.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
    if (userInfo[@"pfquery_request"]) {
        NSLog(@"Starting PFQuery"); // won't print out to console since you're running the watch extension

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *dateTodayShort = [dateToday substringToIndex:[dateToday length] -6];

        // Get JSON file path
        NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Days" ofType:@"json"];
        NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
        NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSArray *days;
        days = JSONDictionary[@"days"];

        // Iterate thru JSON to find Data for Today
        NSObject *todayJson;
        for (NSObject *object in days) {
            NSString *dateObject = [object valueForKey:@"day"];
            if ([dateObject isEqualToString:dateTodayShort]) {
                todayJson = object;
                NSString *textToday = [todayJson valueForKey:@"text"];

                // App Group
                NSString *container = @"group.com.rr.mm";
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];
                [defaults setValue:textToday forKey:@"textSaved"];
            }
        }
        reply(@{@"success": @(YES)});
    } else {
        reply(@{@"success": @(NO)});
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, let me try that!  Also, I don't believe I'll even need to use the `userInfo[@"pfquery_request"] now because I'm using a local static json file, so how would you suggest to construct in the case `userInfo[@"pfquery_request"]` won't exist?  THANKS!

Comment: Are you calling handleWatchKitExtensionRequest multiple times?

Comment: I call it in my `AppDelegate` and then request from both my WatchKit `InterfaceController` and `GlanceController`.  I posted the `InterfaceController` and `GlanceController` code per your request to show that side.

Comment: @SRMR `-willActivate` sometimes will be called multiple times, breakpoint and check.

Answer (score 1):

This crash often happens when a completion block, such as the one in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is accidentally called twice. You haven't posted any code samples, but start by ensuring you haven't done something like called `reply()` twice in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:userInfo:reply:`.

Comment: That helps me zero in a little on what is happening.  I posted my `AppDelegate` code where I'm doing `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:userInfo:reply:`... is this the sort of calling `reply( )` twice that you were telling me I needed to make sure I wasn't doing?  Or is what I have fine?  Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by @Schemetrical, the code you've posted is calling `reply()` twice.

Comment: Ahhh!!  You rock.  I think I'm going to remove the `userInfo[@"pfquery_request"]` if statement too.

Comment: I updated the code to only call `reply( )` once, but its still giving me the same error/crash.  Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Make sure you've re-run the host iOS app to make sure you're using the updated code. Failing that try re-installing.

Comment: By "re-run" do you mean just building again, cleaning it, deleting the app and re-running the app, or something else?  Also, I added my extension code if that's helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, exactly. Just wanted to check. Often people will re-run the WatchKit app target, forgetting that it doesn't necessarily run the new code on the phone.